# jenkins job stuck on '[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables'

Tags: jenkins, azure-virtual-machine

I've had this problem where I send a job to one of my nodes and sometimes the job would stuck on

`[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.`

The issue started when I moved my Jenkins machine from Amazon EC2 to Azure VM. Everytime it occured, I have stopped and relaunched the agent on the node, just so in a few minutes/hours it would freeze again. Usually I would stop the job after a few minutes, but if I let it run, in ~15 minutes I would receive the following:

`FATAL: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel`

I have tried the following solutions, but with no help:

1. Rename the job
2. Create a new job (which runs just a basic command)
3. Uncheck the 'Use TCP_NODELAY flag on the SSH connection'
4. Adding '-Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval=2' to the JVM options

My architecture at the time was:

- Jenkins as docker container on Azure VM (Ubuntu 18.04)
- Jenkins ver 2.202
- SSH Build Agents plugin version 1.31.1
- Node on MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that sort of solved the problem, (now it occurs once in a few days, or even better) was adding `ClientAliveInterval 120` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and relaunch the com.openssh.sshd

`sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd`

`sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd`